# Drag and Drop to pop up add new modal form with pre-filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a new functionality to my Spring web application. I have an add new button on the home page and clicking it will pop up a modal with form to allow people to input something and submit. What I want is to allow dragging some text and dropover mouse on the add button, then the form modal displayed with one of the input field filled with the text dragged. Any solution on this?

Comment: Can you post something that you have already tried or are trying?

Comment: @Nikhil, I have no idea on what to try, that's why I am asking for a solution to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the modal, I suggest you use [bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

You need to be more specific as to from the "some text" you want to drag and drop will come from.

HTML5's [drag and drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) has some easy javascript to get you started

Comment: Thank you, my page has modal implemented with bootstrap modal and I would take example what I need. On my modal there are 2 inputs - title and content to allow input and store for later usage. The scenario is if I see something useful on internet and want to save it, I could do copy and paste or I can drag what I need and drop over the button to display the form with content field being filled with what I drag. I do not know which solution I can use for this part. The htmls drag and drop only shows on 2 elements. Hope this is enough :)